# Generating HTML with inclosed HTML stored in DB

Tags: html, delphi, encoding, utf-8, delphi-xe

I'm generating HTML pages with dynamic content. Users can personalize their pages, by adding a footer. My user control panel stores the footer in a UFT-8 table (MySQL). The footer itself can have HTML.

When I generate my page I'm inserting the footer inside a DIV. My doctype is

```
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'+
               '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+#10+
               '<head>'+#10+
               '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />'+#10+
```

This works, but accentuation and characters like "•", don't display correctly. I've tried using HTMLEscape, but it's breaking the footer HTML.

My question is: what is the most simple way to correct this, without iterating all the special chars and escaping them one by one.

Comment: Are you serving up the content as UTF-8? Are unicode strings being used throughout the process? Have the character been preserved in client->DB->client process? (If they don't make it that far, they will never make it to the client.) General HTML *escaping* only needs to be used to encode "special characters" like `<` (which can mitigate vulnerabilities such as `<script>` injection) and there is no point performing a general HTML *character entity transformations* if UTF-8 is working.

Comment: Also, instead of storing direct HTML, I'd recommend storing a markup/markdown that can be later be generated into injection-free HTML.

Comment: The DB storage is correct. Also when the footer doesn't have any HTML the display under my dynamic page is ok, even if there are accentuated characters, just by using HTMLEscape.

Answer (score 0):

Things I would check:

- does the compiler issue warnings about string conversion problems?
- can you save the HTML to a file, and open it with an editor like Notepad++ to verify it is UTF-8 encoding?
- does the web server set the [Content-Type header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) to `text/html; charset=utf-8`?

Comment: I'm not sure about point 3. I'm using ICS components. I'll check that. Thanks!